# Trying to enable jupyter_http_over_ws but keep getting validation failed: [Win error 5] access denied

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am trying to enable jupyter server extension so that I can run jupyter notebook on colab, I tried to run this command and I get this error:

```
C:\Users\dellb>jupyter server extension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
Enabling: jupyter_http_over_ws
- Writing config: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\etc\jupyter
- Validating jupyter_http_over_ws...
  jupyter_http_over_ws  ok
  X Validation failed: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\etc'
```

Anyone got a fix for this.

Comment: Might be related to the project being version 0.0.8, unmaintained for several years and the last Python version label in `setup.py` being 3.6.